# Customise Json Serialisation of properties per class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-5, system.text.json

The new System.Text.Json serialiser supports setting a naming policy as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions {
    PropertyNamingPolicy = myPolicy
}
```

However these options are applied across the whole serialisation event.

I want to customise properties in different ways for different classes.
In my scenario, I have two classes, both inherit from Dictionary<string, object> and supply additional properties. I want the KEYS of class A to be serialised as all lowercase field names, while the KEYS of class B should be serialised as lowercase with a special string prefix.

Deserialisation is not a concern or consideration for this code.

Edit: I do need the properties on the dictionary serialised as well and have noticed this doesn't happen currently.

Eg.

```
public class Product : Dictionary<string, object> {
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public IList<Store> Stores { get; set; }
}
public class Store : Dictionary<string, object> {
    public string StoreId { get; set; }
}
...
IEnumerable<Product> products = GetProducts();
```

Output expected for 'products':

```
[
  {
    "productid": "1234",
    "somefield" "fhsdjkfsd",
    "stores": [
      {
        "storeid": "abc",
        "prefix_somefield": "somevalue",
        "prefix_foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "storeid": "def",
        "prefix_another": "val"
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    "productid": "456",
    "anotherfield": "fjaskdas"
  }
]
```

Comment: Use a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#support-dictionary-with-non-string-key) for this purpose.  Do you want to serialize the dictionary properties as well as they keys and values?  If so this is the only option in .NET 5.  If you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] we could probably help you with creating the converter.

Comment: I did read the doco on converters, but it looked like I would end up needing to customise the entire serialisation of that class. Because these are the only two classes in my object graph, this felt no different from just using a StringBuilder to build me own output